# Using Relative Paths to Load Resources in Cocoa/C++

Tags: cocoa, resources, path, bundle, nsbundle

I am currently working directly with Cocoa for the first time to built a screen saver. Now I came across a problem when trying to load resources from within the `.saver` bundle. I basically have a small C++ wrapper class to load `.exr` files using `freeImage`. This works as long as I use absoulte paths, but that's not very useful, is it? So, basically, I tried everything: putting the `.exr` file at the level of the `.saver` bundle itself, inside the bundles Resources folder, and so on.

Then I simply tried to load the `.exr` like this, but without success:

```
particleTex = [self loadExrTexture:@"ball.exr"];
```

I also tried making it go to the `.saver` bundles location like this:

```
particleTex = [self loadExrTexture:@"../../../ball.exr"];
```

...to maybe load the `.exr` from that location, but without success.

I then came across this:

```
NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ball" ofType:@"exr"];
const char * pChar = [path UTF8String];
```

...which seems to be a common way to find resources in Cocoa, but for some reason it's empty in my case. Any ideas about that?
I really tried out anything that came to my mind without success so I would be glad about some input!

Comment: Okay, I just found that NSString * path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; points me to the ScreenSaver.app running my screensaver, so I guess the resources need to be relative to that? how would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use NSBundle [`bundleWithIdentifier:`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-BCIBBIGC) instead of `mainBundle` to get a reference to your screen saver bundle.

From the *discussion* section:

> This method is typically used by
>   frameworks and plug-ins to locate
>   their own bundle at runtime. This
>   method may be somewhat more efficient
>   than trying to locate the bundle using
>   the bundleForClass: method.